# Windows Tablet directly capture photo for browser upload

Tags: windows, browser, camera, upload, capture

I'm try to achieve somehow a functionality on Windows 10/11 browser like in mobile browsers on in Android/iOS.

When I open an website there i need to attach a picture in mobile when I press the button first there menu for camera or search files already stored on the device.

In windows on the same website I'm having directly the classic window for open files. I would like to somehow take picture live while browsing the website eliminating the need to have the picture saved in advanced.

Any idea?

Thanks

I try to find an Extension for Edge or Chrome but no success.